# Spicy Hard Cider

Tags: cider

So I enjoy spicy beers from time to time (when they're done well). Chili porters, jalapeno/habanero IPAs, etc. I have a friend who loves spicy things but also has Celiac's and so can't drink beer. Anyone know of any spicy hard ciders out there or spicy gluten-free beers that might work for someone who's gluten-free? One available in Southern California is preferable.

A little internet searching turned up the following two, but at least one of the two isn't available in San Diego:

[Finn River](http://www.finnriver.com/cidery/products/habanero-cider) (Washington state based, might be here),
[Rate Beer page for Finn River](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/finnriver-cider-habanero-cider/209974/)

[McClure's](http://www.mccluresorchard.com/hard-cider-list.html) (Indiana based), 
[Rate Beer for McClure's](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/mcclures-jalapeno/185092/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wandering Aengus Ciderworks of Salem, OR has a chili cider, though it might be only available on tap.   Their website does say that their bottles are now being distributed in So Cal.
http://anthemcider.com/?p=50

https://untappd.com/b/wandering-aengus-ciderworks-anthem-chili/405571

Answer (score 4):

[Blake's](http://www.blakeshardcider.com/) makes a mango habanero hard cider called El Chavo. It's not insanely spicy, but it's got some heat and good flavor.

https://untappd.com/b/blake-s-hard-cider-company-el-chavo/759928

They've also actually just come out with an imperial version of this stuff called [El Chapo](http://www.blakeshardcider.com/portfolio-posts/coming-soon-el-chapo/?age-verified=3262f8efcd)
 that's aged in tequila barrels.